# Apply conditional formatting to a range of cells if a specific cell is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a range of cells.

If cell 'C5' as per picture is not empty then apply colour yellow to cells C6:C12.

What I have tried changes the colour of only one cell i.e. just C6.

Answer (score 1):

Please try selecting C6:C12, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=C$5<>""
```

and chose yellow, Done.

Comment: I did the same but it's only applying condition on the first cell in defined range that is C6. Please confirm if conditional formatting works on cell range using custom formula or script is required for this. As conditional formatting works on range if we use function other than Custom formula.

Comment: I did the same as you suggested but problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

To achive that, you should select the Cells you want the conditional formatting to apply to, and then set the Formatting to "Custom formular", which should be

`=$C$5<>""`

The `$` means, that neither the Column nor Row should advance with the target area.
So 
`=$G1<>""` 
would mean, that if your Target Area was `A1:F4` (the first four cells of the first six columns), that the formatting would depend on `G1` for `A1:F1`, on `G2` for `A2:F2` and so on (the Row is advancing in this example, while the column is still fixed as being `G`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need both `$` - i.e. `=$C$5<>""`

Just tested and works here.